# window.location.reload() not the exact same as refresh button

Tags: javascript, php

Let's say on `page1.php` I have a form. Upon submit, the user gets redirected to `page2.php`, which takes in the PHP `$_POST[]` parameters.

Next, when I refresh `page2.php` manually using the browser's refresh button, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` is set to `page1.php`.

But when I refresh `page2.php` using `window.location.reload()`, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` is set to `page2.php`, being the page it's currently at. (Hitting the back button would result in a `ERR_CACHE_MISS`on Chrome).

I don't like that second part, because I want to redirect them to the previous page at some point, so `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` should always be `page1.php`.

Is there a way to programmatically refresh the page using javascript, exactly the same as you would when clicking the refresh button of the browser?

Comment: Have you tried window.history.go(0) ?

Comment: Is that the same as `window.history.back()`? That I tried, same issue...

Comment: No, it's not, it reloads the current page

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. Tested it, but same behavior as `window.location.reload();`

Comment: Well, why do you want to reload the page anyway? Why don't you just do something like window.location.href = "page1.php"?

Comment: I think this is an XY problem. Why do you need to refresh the page with JS if you also want to remember the previous page? I suspect your use case may benefit from using AJAX instead of an actual full-page refresh.